# I'm trying to calculate 3 days from today, but not include weekend or holidays, but

Tags: date, google-sheets

The workday function should work for this.  I have a Range called "Holidays".  The problem is that workdays doesn't count the weekend days.  I need to count the weekend days.  BUT, if the 3rd day comes on a weekend or a holiday choose the next non-weekend or non-holiday day.  `A2` is the Effective Date of the contract, which is the start date.  I'm trying to calculate the day on which the Earnest Money is due.  See the attached chart as to how it should calculate.[image]

`=if(OR(A5="",A5>workday(A2,3,Holidays)),workday(A2,3,Holidays),"")` is the formula I have but it works for Effective dates that fall on a Sunday, Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday, but not for Effective dates that fall on a Thursday, Friday, Saturday.

Answer (score 1):

### Starting from Today

Use this formula to get the dates starting from today

```
={ArrayFormula(
  VLOOKUP(WEEKDAY(SEQUENCE(7,1,TODAY(),1),2),
  {SEQUENCE(7),{"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday";"Saturday";"Sunday"}},2)),
 BYROW(SEQUENCE(7,1,TODAY(),1),
 LAMBDA(d, VLOOKUP(WEEKDAY(IF(IFNA(MATCH(d+3,F2:F13*1,0),"")="",d+3,d+4),2),
                   {SEQUENCE(7),{"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday";"Saturday";"Sunday"}},2)))}
```

[image]

### Starting from Monday

```
={ArrayFormula(
 VLOOKUP(WEEKDAY(SEQUENCE(7,1,TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3),1),2),
         {SEQUENCE(7),{"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday";"Saturday";"Sunday"}},2)),
 BYROW(SEQUENCE(7,1,TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3),1),
 LAMBDA(d, VLOOKUP(WEEKDAY(IF(IFNA(MATCH(d+3,F2:F13*1,0),"")="",d+3,d+4),2),
                   {SEQUENCE(7),{"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday";"Saturday";"Sunday"}},2)))}
```

[image]

### Starting from Monday using Lambda

Starting from the current week monday.

```
=ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(vl,wd,
 {VLOOKUP(WEEKDAY(wd,2),vl,2),
  BYROW(wd,LAMBDA(d, VLOOKUP(WEEKDAY(IF(IFNA(MATCH(d+3,F2:F13*1,0),"")="",d+3,d+4),2),vl,2)))})
 ({SEQUENCE(7),{"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday";"Saturday";"Sunday"}},
  SEQUENCE(7,1,TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3),1)))
```

[image]

**Explanation**
You need the [Calendar Year 20xx Legal Public Holidays](https://edpm.dc.gov/issuances/legal-public-holidays-2023/#:%7E:text=Calendar%20Year%202023%20Legal%20Public%20Holidays) to skip one day if matched the legal holidays date after adding 3 days.

Used formulas help
[**`BYROW`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) - [**`SEQUENCE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) - [**`TODAY`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`VLOOKUP`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) - [**`IF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) - [**`IFNA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944) - [**`MATCH`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) - [**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)

Comment: Thank you but these seem extremely complicated.  I put out something on the Microsoft forums and he came up with a formula, however, I'm using Sheets for this and his `LET` function wouldn't work and he gave me a smart ass answer when I asked him to convert this to work in Sheets, basically telling me to go to the sheets forum.  Here is his formula. `=LET(date1,A2+3,date2,date1+MAX(3-WEEKDAY(date1,16),0),WORKDAY(date2-1,1,Holidays))`. After some work, I have it working in Sheets and here it is.  `=WORKDAY(A2+3+MAX(3-WEEKDAY(A2+3,16),0)-1,1,Holidays)`